# How can I match classes in a Scala "match" statement?

Tags: scala

How can I use a "match" statement to identify the value of a class variable?  The following is invalid, and I can't find an acceptable variant -- other than if ... else if ... else ...

```
val c: Class[_] = classOf[Int]
val what = c match { case classOf[Int] => "int!"; case classOf[Float] => "float!" }
```

The compiler complains: `error: not found: type classOf`

And of course, I can't use `Class[Int]` because that type information is erased:

```
c match { case Class[Int] => "int!"; case Class[Float] => "float!" }
error: type Class of type Class does not take type parameters.
```

I've also tried variants like `Int.class`, all to no avail.  (And I don't really want to convert to strings: I feel it's important to have the compiler catch renamed/moved classes.)

Am I being dense, or have I stumbled into a Scala blind spot?

Comment: Well, the answers below are correct (and thanks for the answers!) but it increasingly appears this *is* a kind of ugly hole in Scala. Classes are singletons, so there's no reason you should have to assign them to variables in order to match them efficiently -- nor resort to using a cascading series of ifs, written as guards or separate statements.  But so it is, apparently.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can match on class values if you create a stable identifier (ie. a val) for them,

```
scala> val c: Class[_] = classOf[Int]
c: Class[_] = int

scala> val ClassOfInt = classOf[Int]
ClassOfInt: java.lang.Class[Int] = int

scala> val ClassOfFloat = classOf[Float]
ClassOfFloat: java.lang.Class[Float] = float

scala> val what = c match {
     |     case ClassOfInt => "int!"
     |     case ClassOfFloat => "float!"
     | }
what: String = int!
```

Note that you can't match on type (ie. Class[Int]) because erasure means that the different type instantiations of Class[T] are indistinguishable at runtime ... hence the warning below

```
scala> val what = c match {
     |     case _: Class[Int] => "int!"
     |     case _: Class[Float] => "float!"
     | }
warning: there were 2 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
what: java.lang.String = int!
```

Comment: Stable identifiers - yes, I was afraid of that.  Hideous.  "Note that you can't match on type (ie. Class[Int])" -- yes, noted in question.  Thank you, though!

Comment: (I should also note that this answer is potentially more efficient than the one below, so it's closer to what I'm looking for.  Thanks again!)

Comment: An important note: the name of the `val` must begin with an upper case.

Answer (score 31):

The verbose case comparison works:

```
val what = c match {
  case q if q == classOf[Int] => "int!"
  case q if q == classOf[Float] => "float!"
}
```

Of course, being a lower-case identifier, `classOf` should not work directly in a case statement anyway. However, neither does an escaped

```
case `classOf`[Int]
```

work in this case, so you’ll have to go with the `if`-guard.

Comment: Yes, the if-guard works... converting the `case` statement into a set of `if/else` statements.  Ugly, but quite correct.  Thank you!

Comment: @Debilski is there any other solution than ugly if/else statement, which does not make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and placing the class in a 'stable identifier' wasn't that practical.  I found the next best thing was to have tidy 'else if' statements.

Using this method:

```
private def is[T <: AnyRef : Manifest](implicit cls: Class[_]) = 
    cls == manifest[T].runtimeClass
```

I can write:

```
  implicit val arg = cls   
  if (is[ClassA]) ...
  else if (is[ClassB]) ...
  ...
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class: " + cls)
```

Comment: Ha ha.  I just found my own answer again but I can't vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

To consider inheritance:

```
val what = c match {
  case q if classOf[Int].isAssignableFrom(q) => "int!"
  case q if classOf[Float].isAssignableFrom(q)  => "float!"
}
```