# Play 2.1 getControllerInstance usage?

Tags: playframework

What is the intended usage pattern for getControllerInstance on GlobalSettings?  Is it possible to use it without a dependency injection framework?

the signature is `getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A`

So, from what I understand, this gets called on any route that is specified with the `@` prefix, and you must return an instance of that type of controller (`A`).  But if `A` is the parameterized type of `Class` it is subject to type erasure at runtime, correct?  How can I know which controller class is being asked for?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way that looks very non-Scala, but works for me.

```
override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
  if (controllerClass == classOf[CardsService]) ComponentsRegistry.cardsService.asInstanceOf[A]
  else super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass)
}
```

I absolutely agree that it's ugly and will be happy to see better solution.

Unfortunately it's not possible to use pattern matching here to make this code a little more idiomatic: [How can I match classes in a Scala "match" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157143/how-can-i-match-classes-in-a-scala-match-statement)