# scala correct way for pattern matching using reflection

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

trying to refactor and improve this pattern matching :

```
abstract class SuperClass
case class Foo() extends SuperClass
case class Bar() extends SuperClass

def getTheClass(param:String)={
 Class.forName(param)
}

val bazz = getTheClass(classOf[Foo].getName)

bazz match{
  case b if b == classOf[Bar] => "I am Bar"
  case f if f == classOf[Foo] => "I am Foo"
}
```

is there elegant way without the guards ?

Comment: Do you really need to construct bazz from string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I match classes in a Scala "match" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157143/how-can-i-match-classes-in-a-scala-match-statement)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella it is not duplicate although there are matching , I am asking for a different solution

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes, Otherwise will use other matching :)

Comment: @igx you're right that it's not strictly a duplicate (I retracted my "close" vote), although the accepted answer is the same that also applies to you: you can create stable identifiers for `classOf[Bar]` and `classOf[Foo]`, which would simplify the pattern matching itself (although overall it would not improve things a lot over what you currently have)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Thanks , yes, it is an option , but actually in this case, like you wrote, I don't see much improvement if any) , maybe what I have is good enough

Answer (score 1):

Matching based entirely on strings:

```
abstract class SuperClass
case class Foo() extends SuperClass
case class Bar() extends SuperClass

val FooClass = classOf[Foo].getName
val BarClass = classOf[Bar].getName

val bazz = classOf[Foo].getName

bazz match{
  case BarClass => "I am Bar"
  case FooClass => "I am Foo"
}
```